# Python 2.7. ImportError: No module named setuptools_rust and a Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: python, ubuntu-16.04, ros

I'm trying to install ROS on Ubuntu 16.04 through my virtual machine. However, I get the following errors and have no idea how to fix it. I've tried to do

```
pip install setuptools
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install -y python-setuptools
```

as recommended by other posts.

The readout I get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1 in <module>
  File "/tmp/pip-build-6p7tTc/crytography/setup.py", line 14, in <module> 
    from setuptools_rust import RustExtension
ImportError: No module named setuptools_rust

------------------------------------------------

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in/tmp/pip-build-op7tTc/cryptography/
```

Comment: `setup tools` with a space is just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
pip install setuptools-rust
```

After the installation of setuptools-rust python library, ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools-rust' error will be solved. Check if it works out with the other error.

Comment: When I run that, it gives me the second error.

Comment: Okay, did you also try what @tripleee said? And I just google searched. There seem seem s to be quite some threads on this issue. Can you try those and check once?